# Are there some efforts to add rigor to the quantum field theory?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I am quite interested in putting a firm mathematical foundation on QFT. However, I have not been able to find a professor or an institution doing such a work. Do there exist certain areas of work in which people are engaged in rigorously defining and proving the concepts and contents of QFT? I am just very curious.

Comment: [Axiomatic quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_quantum_field_theory)

Comment: [A Perspective on Constructive Quantum Field Theory, 
Stephen J. Summers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3991)